# Continuity condition of the derivative for the function to be linear

Tags: calculus

We are given some properties of a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$:

$f'(x)$ is defined everywhere

The function satisfies $f'(x) = f'\left({\frac{x}{{2^n}}} \right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$

The questions are:

Can we verify that $f(x)$ is linear if $f'(x)$ is continuous?
Do we have to have the condition of $f'(x)$ being continuous at all points to verify that $f(x)$ is a linear function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can answer the first question affirmatively, for if $f'$ is continuous, then the sequential characterization of continuity together with the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{2^n}=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ implies

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=f'(0)\text{ for every }x\in\mathbb R$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(x)=f'(x)$, we get $f'(x)=f'(0)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$. After integrating, this gives $f(x)=f'(0)x+C$ for some constant $C$, so $f$ is linear.

Note that this argument proves we don't need $f'$ to be continuous everywhere to get this result; all we need is for $f'$ to be continuous at $0$. This answers the second question.